# Performance of different filtering methods with an optional parameter

Tags: sql-server

This is the scenario, some SP parameters can be optional which means they'll contain NULL or they can contain a value, like an integer for example, and I've been using always something similar to:

```
select (fields) 
from table_name tn 
where 1=1 
and (  
   @parameter is null
   or ( @parameter is not null and tn.columnname = @parameter ) 
)
```

and now, I realized that the next option is better than the one above:

```
select (fields) 
from table_name tn 
where 1=1 
and (  
   1 = ( case when @parameter is null then 1 when tn.columnname = @parameter then 1 else 0 end )
)
```

The question is: Why?

It's assumed that we must avoid conditional clauses like IIFs or CASE WHENs in the whole query.

Comment: When you say "I realized that the next option is better" what is your definition of "better"?

Comment: And what do you mean by your last "its assumed" comment? Who is assuming that and why?

Comment: The query runs faster with the second option than the 1st one;

Comment: Have you compared the execution plans?

Comment: Not yet, I don't know much about execution plans, maybe the cost of the second option is greater than the first one but, its faster :S.

Comment: All discussed in great detail by Erland [here](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html)

Comment: `option (recompile)` will be your friend here.

Comment: To get an answer to your question I recommend moving it to https://dba.stackexchange.com/